# Python3 unable to import argcomplete package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to import "argcomplete" package but I'm facing following error:

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed86e0, Oct  3 2017, 00:32:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import argcomplete
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'argcomplete'
>>> exit()
```

I confirm that argcomplete was successfully installed:

```
#pip3 install argcomplete
Collecting argcomplete
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/88/ba8d8684a8a27749250c66ff7c2b408fdbc29b50da61200338ff9b2607bf/argcomplete-1.9.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Installing collected packages: argcomplete
Successfully installed argcomplete-1.9.4

$ more test_backend.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python
# PYTHON_ARGCOMPLETE_OK
"""
Run module with test data
"""

$ cd /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
apple site-packages
$ ls -ltrh arg*
-rw-r--r--  1 apple  admin    87K May 27 03:34 argparse.py

argcomplete-1.9.4.dist-info:
total 104
-rw-r--r--  1 apple  admin    12B May 27 15:38 top_level.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 apple  admin   1.5K May 27 15:38 metadata.json
-rw-r--r--  1 apple  admin   110B May 27 15:38 WHEEL
-rw-r--r--  1 apple  admin   2.0K May 27 15:38 RECORD
-rw-r--r--  1 apple  admin    16K May 27 15:38 METADATA
-rw-r--r--  1 apple  admin     4B May 27 15:38 INSTALLER
-rw-r--r--  1 apple  admin    14K May 27 15:38 DESCRIPTION.rst

argcomplete:
total 160
-rw-r--r--  1 apple  admin   2.1K May 27 15:38 shellintegration.py
-rw-r--r--  1 apple  admin    13K May 27 15:38 my_shlex.py
-rw-r--r--  1 apple  admin    15K May 27 15:38 my_argparse.py
-rw-r--r--  1 apple  admin   3.6K May 27 15:38 completers.py
-rw-r--r--  1 apple  admin   524B May 27 15:38 compat.py
 drwxr-xr-x  3 apple  admin   102B May 27 15:38 bash_completion.d
-rw-r--r--  1 apple  admin   1.4K May 27 15:38 _check_module.py
drwxr-xr-x  9 apple  admin   306B May 27 15:38 __pycache__
-rw-r--r--  1 apple  admin    29K May 27 15:38 __init__.py
```

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ is already added to PATH

I noticed that import is only working from directory /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages but not from anywhere else

```
$ python3 -c 'import argcomplete'
>> successful


$ cd /Users/apple/Desktop/XXXXX/
apple (master) XXXXX
$ python3 test_backend.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_backend.py", line 11, in <module>
    import argcomplete
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'argcomplete'
apple (master) XXXXX
$ python3 -c 'import argcomplete'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'argcomplete'
apple (master) XXXXX
```

Please advise how to solve this issue, thanks.

Comment: Is there an installed python 2x on your computer?

Comment: yes python2.7 is also installed on this computer

Comment: Can you let me know the output of `which python3` ?

Comment: Does `site-packages` appear in `python3 -c “import sys; print(sys.path)`?

Comment: @Kaxil here is the o/p of which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: @Megalng, no it doesn't appear in sys.path. $ python3
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed86e0, Oct  3 2017, 00:32:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> for p in sys.path:
...     print(p)
... 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Comment: @A.Midany I have posted the answer. Try running that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that python 2.7 is the default for mac so installing packages via terminal will only install them on python 2.7.

If you already have pip installed on version 3, just do this:

```
python3 -m pip install argcomplete
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, i thought that "pip3 install <package>" should be doing same job, can you clarify the difference?

Comment: @A.Midany I'm sorry I don't have an answer for you, I just know that this works even if you do not have pip's path set up.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following to install `argcomplete` in python3 :

**In Terminal:**

```sh
python3
```

**In Python3 console:**

```py
import pip

def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])


install('argcomplete')
```

And then try using `argcomplete` complete package from within the python console.